# Index page is not working

Tags: themes, pages

I need help!

I am farely new to WordPress and I was setting up a client a small blog for him. When I was done, I tested it on my server and everything was working perfectly with it. The next day I went to send it to him for approval and I got this message:

Your website is ready.
This site has been successfully created and is ready for content to be added. Replace this default page with your own index page.

Can anyone explain what that means? I can view the post pages but I can not view the index page.

Thanks

Comment: Check for a index.html page on the root of the web server  ?

Comment: Can you link to the site in question? As-written, this question is almost impossible to answer.

Comment: The site name is www.culturefaith.com

Comment: I also made sure that the index.php is in the root folder, which it is.

Comment: I found the answer. There was a index.html file loaded on the server which was conflicting with the index.php file. Once I deleted it from the server it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that there is an `index.html` or an `index.htm` file in that directory which is getting priority over WordPress's `index.php`. Remove or rename that `.htm?` file.

For reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html See the `DirectoryIndex` part.